# Can't change cipher suite in TLS 1.3 handshake (OpenSSL)

Tags: c, openssl, handshake, tls1.3

I'm trying to test all cipher suites supported by TLS 1.3. (TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256)

Here below the localhost server code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

SSL_CTX* create_server_context() {
    SSL_CTX* ctx;
    
    // Initialize the SSL library
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    
    // Create an SSL/TLS context
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_server_method());
    if (!ctx) {
        perror("SSL_CTX_new() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Set the server certificate and private key
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "server.crt", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "server.key", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Set the list of supported cipher suites
    if (SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites(ctx, "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256") != 1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    return ctx;
}

void handle_client_connection(SSL* ssl) {
    char buffer[1024];
    int bytes;
    
    // Receive data from the client
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (bytes <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Print the data received from the client
    printf("Received: %.*s\n", bytes, buffer);
    
    // Send a response to the client
    const char* response = "Hello, client!\n";
    SSL_write(ssl, response, strlen(response));
    
    // Close the SSL connection
    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    SSL_free(ssl);
}

int main() {
    int server_fd, client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    SSL_CTX* ctx;
    
    // Create an SSL/TLS context
    ctx = create_server_context();
    
    // Create a TCP socket
    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_fd < 0) {
        perror("socket() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Set the server address
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(4433); // Port 4433 for HTTPS
    
    // Bind the server address to the socket
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Start listening for incoming connections
    if (listen(server_fd, 5) < 0) {
        perror("listen() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("Server started. Waiting for connections...\n");
    
    // Accept incoming connections
    while (1) {
        // Accept a new connection
        client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_len);
        if (client_fd < 0) {
            perror("accept() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        printf("Client connected.\n");
        
        // Create an SSL object for this connection
        SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        if (!ssl) {
            perror("SSL_new() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        // Associate the SSL socket with the TCP socket
        if (SSL_set_fd(ssl, client_fd) != 1) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        // Start the SSL/TLS handshake procedure
        if (SSL_accept(ssl) != 1) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        // Handle the client connection
        handle_client_connection(ssl);
    }
    
    // Close the SSL context
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    
    // Close the server socket
    close(server_fd);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Commands to generate server.key, server.csr and server.crt

`openssl ecparam -out server.key -name prime256v1 -genkey`

`openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj "/CN=localhost"`

`openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt`

Here the supported openssl ciphersuites (openssl versions -v):

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384         TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256   TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256         TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384    TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305    TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384      TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384        TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256          TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256        TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256          TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA         TLSv1   Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA           TLSv1   Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA             SSLv3   Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA         TLSv1   Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA           TLSv1   Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA             SSLv3   Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384      TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305      TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305    TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-GCM-SHA384              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
AES128-GCM-SHA256              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256          TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA256                  TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA256
AES128-SHA256                  TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384    TLSv1   Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA       TLSv1   Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA        SSLv3   Kx=SRP      Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA            SSLv3   Kx=SRP      Au=SRP   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384      TLSv1   Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA384
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384      TLSv1   Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA384
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA         SSLv3   Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA         SSLv3   Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA                     SSLv3   Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384          TLSv1   Kx=PSK      Au=PSK   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA384
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA             SSLv3   Kx=PSK      Au=PSK   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256    TLSv1   Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA       TLSv1   Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA        SSLv3   Kx=SRP      Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA            SSLv3   Kx=SRP      Au=SRP   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256      TLSv1   Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256      TLSv1   Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA         SSLv3   Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA         SSLv3   Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA                     SSLv3   Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256          TLSv1   Kx=PSK      Au=PSK   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA             SSLv3   Kx=PSK      Au=PSK   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
```

I have tried all these commands to establish a connection and they work but always with the same cipher suite (TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384).

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 
openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

Output of one of these:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=0 CN = localhost
verify error:num=18:self-signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = localhost
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = localhost
   i:CN = localhost
   a:PKEY: id-ecPublicKey, 256 (bit); sigalg: ecdsa-with-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Feb 25 20:14:42 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Mar 26 20:14:42 2024 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLURRED
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = localhost
issuer=CN = localhost
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 664 bytes and written 321 bytes
Verification error: self-signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 18 (self-signed certificate)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: BLURRED
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: BLURRED
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    BLURRED

    Start Time: 1708893184
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self-signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: BLURRED
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: BLURRED
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    BLURRED

    Start Time: 1708893184
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self-signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK

Hello, client!
closed
```

All the commands output have this part in common:

```
.
.
.
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 18 (self-signed certificate)
.
.
.
```

Comment: All `s_client -cipher` values you showed are TLS1.2 suites. Since both your `openssl` program and your server are capable of 1.3, they will never negotiate any 1.2 suite, and by default always the same 1.3 suite. If you want to choose a 1.3 suite from commandline, look at the `-help` message or man page for the (different) option that selects 1.3 suite(s). If you want to choose a 1.2 suite, also specify `-tls1_2` or `-no_tls1_3`.

Comment: ok thanks, and is there any change that I have to do server side to enable TLS1.3? How can I choose Key exchange and Authentication algorithms? Also because if I try to execute `openssl s_client -connect localhost:4433 -cipher TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` I obtain `Call to SSL_CONF_cmd(-cipher, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256) failed
4077668E347F0000:error:0A0000B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match:../ssl/ssl_lib.c:2745:`

Comment: As I said, **to choose a 1.3 suite use the correct option NOT REPEAT NOT `-cipher`**. And no you don't need to change anything in the server to support 1.3 -- just read your own question, you already posted the log of successful 1.3 connection to this server.